# Forensic examination of a GPS Tracker Model Type: TK905-2g-V5.0

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, spi, uart, flash

A few weeks ago a friend of mine found a GPS Tracke Device under his car.  This is scary. On top of the case there is a branding sticker "winnes". We want to know, who did this, so we need to analyze the storage and settings to get notice e.g. on which locations and when the device was in use before some one mounted it to my friends vehicle. [image: eWinnes TK905 GPS Tracker Device]

I'm a computer and electronics enthusiast but still need your help to examine what we can get from the internals.

There is a SIM Card slot and Micro USB Port. Connecting USB to a Computer only charges the internal LiPo battery (3,7 Volts, 10.000 mAh, 37Wh) but Device Manager / dmesg does not recognize any connected device. There is no switch to turn something on or off. When the device was found there was still 3.7 Volts in the Battery. So I cut off the power lines and desoldered the ceramic GPS antenna to avoid overwriting memory when powering on to be able to do something like UART communication.

Internal there is a **Quectel MC25MB-04-STD** (GSM/GPRS/GNSS) module. I could not find any none chinese datasheet to get pinout for UART/I2C/SPI, but maybe u speak chinese and can help with it: https://www.quectel.com/cn/product/gsm-gprs-gnss-mc25

On top of the MC25MB there is a FCCID: https://fccid.io/CMIIT-ID-2018CP8985

**What we try to find out:**

- historical data about gps position and time stamp
- APN Settings IP/Port/Device PIN of the tracking portal

[image]
[image]
[image]

Open Image in a new tab will give u more insights.

**Details:**

Under the aluminium plate of the MC25MB there is:

1. HS8225H --- Mobile RF front-end chip
2. AT6558 --- a high-performance BDS/GNSS multi-mode satellite navigation
   receiver SOC single chip, on that integrated RF front-end, digital baseband processor,
   32 bit CPU RISC, power management functions.
3. **RDA8955L** --- GSM 850/900/1800/1900 Quad-Band
   SOC Processor (**Integrated 32Mb 1.8V SPI NOR Flash** + Integrated 32Mb 1.8V DDR PSRAM)

I doesnt own a Spectrum analyzer but for now we could work with:

- CH340G UART-TTL Adapter (3.3 / 5 Volts)
- CH341A SPI / I2C Programmer (modded to 1.8 Volts)
- some multimeters

On the PCB there are multiple testpoints labeled as follows:

- RX / TX / VCHG (at the micro usb port)
- RXD / TXD
- GLDO EN
- GRX / GTX
- VDD
- SOS / GND
- GRX / GTX
- GND / BAT+

Help me solve the mystery who mounted this device to my friends vehicle. What would u suggest to do next and would u agree there should be data stored on a flash memory that could be dumped?

Comment: regarding datasheets that aren't in a language you speak: google translate will accept pdf documents and websites as targets: https://translate.google.ca/?sl=auto&tl=en&op=websites .

Answer (score 1):

Your best option may be to hire a professional who has experience in such reverse engineering. Otherwise the chances of figuring it out are slim unless you want to learn a lot about reverse engineering of embedded systems.

If there's a SIM, or eSIM, your friend may have enough to consult a lawyer with practice in cyberstalking, who knows the right experts, and file a case against the "john doe" who purchased the service. The discovery process will then get the data from the wireless provider about what company manages the wireless data account, then that company can be subpoenaed for other records, eventually leading somewhere. Or nowhere if the company is offshore, as may be the case - unless you can afford an international civil process.

Figure $20k to get the ball rolling if everyone involved is in the US, but it may cost much more depending on how much legal work is involved.

I am NOT a lawyer and this is NOT legal advice.